# Получить все записи из базы

Tags: java, android, json

С сервера приходит JSON ответ:

```
{"id":"4","story":[{"name":"Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу Мяу ","author":"1"}]}
{"id":"3","story":[{"name":"Гав гав гав Гав гав гав Гав гав гав Гав гав гав Гав гав гав Гав гав гав Гав гав гав Гав гав гав Гав гав гав Гав гав гав ","author":"1"}]}
{"id":"2","story":[{"name":"Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла Вторая статья Бла ","author":"1"}]}
{"id":"1","story":[{"name":"Это мего кулл сатья. Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья Это мего кулл сатья ","author":"1"}]}
```

И вот, мне нужно в приложении вывести все значения id, то есть, судя по ответу в базе 4 статьи, значит приложение должно вывести: `Статья 1` `Статья 2` `Статья 3` `Статья 4`

Пытаюсь это сделать так:

```
    class AllStat extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(IndexUserYes.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Опочки...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String[] args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_story, "GET", params);

        try {

            storyAll = json.getString(TAG_ID);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Статья:" + storyAll); //выводим
    }



}
```

В итоге в приложении я получаю лишь `Статья 4` и все. То есть выводит почему то только первую строку ответа, и на этом все.

Answer (score 1):

1. Почитайте доки класса.
2. Разберитесь как, каким образом и во что он преобразует ответ сервера.

В общем случае класс должен ответ сервера преобразовать в массив/список, который вам потом уже надо перебирать.

В вашем же случае вам, похоже, метод вами используемый возвращает лишь последний элемент списка.

---

Попробуйте так (2 минуты гугленья новой темы):

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_story, "GET", params);
try {
       JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ID)
       for(int i=0; i<results.lenght(); i++)
       {
          System.out.println("Статья:" + results.get(i));
       }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

---

Либо попробуйте заменить

> storyAll = json.getString(TAG_ID);

на

> storyAll += json.getString(TAG_ID);

Comment: Не один из примеров не работает. на первый ответ получаю ошибку 09-20 13:02:04.938: WARN/System.err(372): org.json.JSONException: Value 14 at id of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray